# How to turn on macbook internal screen without rebooting system when booted as external monitor?

Tags: display, reboot, closed-clamshell

I faced one issue in macbook.
I booted macbook pro as closed lid with external monitor connection and with AC power supply.

But once there is power cut in residence place.
My external monitor is tunned off. (Consider as I am not using UPS.)
How I can turn on macbook internal screen w/o rebooting system to continue my work?

Even macbook screen is not automatically turn on.
What is the solution / shortcut to turn on internal screen w/o rebooting system?

(and ofcourse w/o loosing my work?)

Comment: If opening the lid didn't work, try pressing the power button, but don't hold it longer than 1 second.  Same as waking it from sleep.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Allan: It's not working.